# Angular Bootstrap 4 changebox isn't changing

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to learn some angular basics. I did some checkbox list, but it doesn't change when unchecked. Here is my html component:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="list-group-item">
        <div class="task-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"
            class="list-child"
            (change)="onTaskChange($event,task)"
            [checked]="task.completed">
            <span ngClass="{{task.completed ? 'name completed' : 'name'}}">{{ task.name }}</span>
            <span class="badge {{ getDueDateLabel(task) }} float-right ">{{ task.dueDate }}</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my method in app.component.ts :

```
  getDueDateLabel(task:Task) {
      if(task.completed == true ) {
          return 'badge-success';
      }else {
          console.log('Task changed color')
          return 'badge-danger';

      }
  }
```

In console i don't see a log, so i assume that it doesn't work. I am using Angular 9. Appreciate for any help. Thanks !

Comment: Update task.completed value to false on uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you update the value of `task.completed` on every change, since that is what you bound to `[checked]`?

Comment: I am not sure, i feel like my statement for task.completed = false isn't checking.